# GRUB Boot menu with Windows 10 bootloader appears on single boot system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I've had Ubuntu in a completely new computer and after a few months a dual boot GRUB screen appeared. The only changes I made recently concerned wine, and I tried to download an .iso windows 10 file from my university in order to have it on my other laptop. However the download failed.

After the menu screen appears, if I select the Windows bootloader it says "no such partition found". **It's not a dual boot system**.

Why has this appeared suddenly and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you have Ubuntu only, Windows 10 is irrelevant. It wouldn't have mattered if you were downloading any other ISO, any other file, and even that, successful download or not, has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: If UEFI and you still have the Windows UEFI menu entry of course it will say no partition as your erased Windows. You need to boot the ubuntu entry in UEFI. Some brands want to default to Windows entry in UEFI, what brand/model system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why that appeared from what you describe. But if you want to get rid of the unusable Windows entry, you could reinstall grub.

Just boot into Ubuntu, open a command text window and type

```
sudo update-grub
```

This rescans the partitions for valid other OS and adds them into the list. It would remove a non existing windows partition. Then install it again, e.g on the first or only hard drive `/dev/sda` (adapt as required).

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

This overwrites the current grub files with the updated ones.